# Event gets triggered via ISE but not in normal PS window

Tags: forms, powershell, events

I've tried a lot of "works in ise but not in console" links via Google and especially here on Stackoverflow, but alas nothing I've tried so far worked.

I'll start with the whole code:

```
Param (
    [ValidateRange(2,10)][int]$Time = 5,
    [ValidateLength(4,40)][String]$Title = "Attention $($Env:USERNAME.ToUpper())",
    [ValidateLength(4,40)][String]$Text = "This is a test!",
    [ValidateSet("None","Info","Warning","Error")] $Status = "Info",
    [ValidatePattern("[\\:\-\w\d\s]+.exe")][String]$TrayIcon = (Get-Process -id $pid).Path
)

# sec to ms
$TTL = $Time * 1000

if (![System.IO.File]::Exists($TrayIcon)){
    Write-Host "File does not exist!"
    exit
}

function ClearEvents {
    # Perform  cleanup actions on balloon tip
    $global:balloon.dispose()
    Remove-Variable  -Name balloon  -Scope Global

    Unregister-Event  -SourceIdentifier TrayClicked
    Remove-Job -Name TrayClicked

    Unregister-Event  -SourceIdentifier BallonClicked
    Remove-Job -Name BallonClicked

    Unregister-Event  -SourceIdentifier BalloonClosed
    Remove-Job -Name BalloonClosed

    #test if function is called
    [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show('Hello')
}

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

$global:balloon = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon

# Tray-Icon
$balloon.Icon = [System.Drawing.Icon]::ExtractAssociatedIcon($TrayIcon)

# Balloon
# [System.Windows.Forms.ToolTipIcon] | Get-Member -Static -Type Property
$balloon.BalloonTipIcon = [System.Windows.Forms.ToolTipIcon]::$Status
$balloon.BalloonTipTitle = $Title
$balloon.BalloonTipText = $Text

$balloon.Visible = $true
$balloon.ShowBalloonTip($TTL)

[void](Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $balloon -EventName MouseClick -SourceIdentifier TrayClicked -Action {
    ClearEvents
})
[void](Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $balloon -EventName BalloonTipClicked -SourceIdentifier BallonClicked -Action {
    ClearEvents
})
[void](Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $balloon -EventName BalloonTipClosed -SourceIdentifier BalloonClosed -Action {
    ClearEvents
})
```

Now, when one of the events are triggered (like Balloon clicked), then the "ClearEvents" function gets called (for testing purposes I added a MsgBox).

But in a console these events never trigger! Why is that?

Tested with Win7x64 (PS 3.0) and Win10x64 (PS 5.1)

I've also confirmed with `[System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.GetApartmentState()` that both consoles run indeed with the default "STA" (Single-Threaded Apartment), which apparently some "System.Windows.Forms" need to run correctly.
Unfortunately that's not the problem...

My script is based on this one: https://mcpmag.com/articles/2017/09/07/creating-a-balloon-tip-notification-using-powershell.aspx

Comment: A common cause of these "*works in ISE but not in console*" (or visa versa) issues is actually not the ISE or the console but (`$Global:`) variables that are still available in one instance and not the other. In other words: for troubleshooting/confirming your problem description restart both (the ISE and the console) and confirm that they still behave differently (it could well be that they both work after a restart, but more likely both -including ISE- do not work any more).

Comment: Thanks, I already did restart the ISE or console several times; and on different PCs.